# Liferay theme is not available under {liferay\Temp} folder

Tags: liferay-6, liferay-theme

Just like the portlets, I'm trying to find the theme under `{liferay\Temp}` folder but it is unavailable.

My main goal is to change/update `.VM` code in the theme just like I'm doing under the `Temp\Sample-portlet` for JSP files which do not need compilation, as this process does not require deployment.

I am changing the `.VM` files under `webapps` for the theme, but it is not reflecting in the page.

When deploy it, it takes more time to deploy than normal.

Comment: what thing you are changing in .VM file that also matters.What you are changing in it service or html code or velocity variable or flow of it?

Comment: Well Im trying to edit/update the HTML code only.

Comment: is that your custom theme or core liferay theme you are changing?

Comment: That is my custom theme.